# linq to sharepoint error: Cannot insert an entity that already exists

Tags: data

I have a sharepoint list: MyList

I insert item to this list by Linq to Sharepoint (context object) like this:

```
context.MyList.InsertAllOnSubmit(data.Items.Select(n => dataConvertor.Convert(n)));
context.SubmitChanges();
```

Convert method:

```
MyListItem = new MyListItem()
{
   Column1 = "1";
   Column2 = "2";
   Column3 = "3";
}
```

The data is received from an excel file but for some excel files I get the Error:
Cannot insert an entity that already exists.

I tried to do:

```
var myist = data.Items.Select(n => dataConvertor.Convert(n));
foreach (var item in myList)
{
   context.MyList.InsertOnSubmit(item);
   context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

It worked but because the data is very large it took a lot of time...